# Can UPDATE TOP cause deadlocks?

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I have an SQL table where each row represents an item in my inventory. I'm using this update query to reserve items when they're purchased. I'm having a hard time understanding if I need additional locking mechanism to make sure deadlocks don't occur when multiple requests are executing this query or is this enough on it's own? I'm using MSSQL.

```
UPDATE TOP (@Quantity) [dbo].[Inventory] 
SET IsAvailable = 0, OrderItemId = @OrderItemId 
OUTPUT INSERTED.InventoryId 
WHERE IsAvailable = 1 AND ProductId = @ProductId AND OrderItemId IS NULL;
```

Comment: What are your indexes, and what other queries are you running against the same table? Are you running this in a transaction with other queries or is it just a single statement

Comment: `TOP` doesn't stop dead locks; it just limits the number of rows returned by the statement.

Comment: just a single statement, InventoryId is PK and OrderItemId, ProductId and IsAvailable are non-unique, non-clustered indexes. For the sake of simplicity, I'm not taking into account other queries and basically interested if this one can potentially deadlock if run concurrently against same products.

Comment: Unlikely to deadlock, as the access pattern will probably always be the same: lookup on `ProductId` CI filtering rows according to the `where`, then update the NCIs. Row or page locks on the CI will ensure the next query will block waiting for the other one to finish, but will not deadlock. If you share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com might see a bit more detailed

Comment: thanks, here's the plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkFr6wT-u the query is slightly different as I tried to make it more understandable before posting